# Filtering an ObservableCollection by using an IValueConverter

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, windows-runtime

I'm building a Windows 8 Metro Application where I need to filter an `ObservableCollection`. Sadly, the CollectionViewSource-Class in the WinRT-Framework doesn't support filtering so I try to use an `IValueConverter` for doing so.

My XAML:

```
<RadioButton Content="this Week" GroupName="AppointmentFilter" IsChecked="True" Name="rbtnFilter"/>
<RadioButton Content="all" GroupName="AppointmentFilter"/>
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Appointments, ConverterParameter={Binding rbtnFilter.IsChecked}, Converter={StaticResource Filter}}"/>
```

My IValueConverter:

```
public class AppointmentListFilter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        ObservableCollection<VMAppointment> appointments = value as ObservableCollection<VMAppointment>;
        bool filter = (bool)parameter;

        if (filter)
        {
            return new ObservableCollection<VMAppointment>(appointments.Where(x => x.Date.CompareTo(DateTime.Now.AddDays(7)) <= 0));
        }
        else
        {
            return appointments;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

When the `IValueConverter` is being executed, the parameter "parameter" is null and not a boolean value. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: ConverterParameter does not support any binding operations.

Comment: Are you sure that CollectionViewSource doesn't support filtering under WinRT? I couldn't find any documentation that supported that.

Comment: @DanBusha see here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/winappswithcsharp/thread/fc3705c1-ae0c-483e-a209-8c3aeefd02c8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If binding itself does not support bindings you could change the type of the Appointments property so it includes the parameter you want.
If your converter only gets called once - you could try to subscribe to the ObservableProperty's [CollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ms653375%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event and raise the PropertyChanged event for Appointments every time it happens.